# Disable default .NET MVC Authentication

Tags: android, .net, asp.net-mvc, android-volley

I'm built a simple service to access from my Android device. On the server side I use .NET MVC Application and Volley lib on Android side.

When I run service under IIS on server, it works fine, but when it is started from VisualStudio, Volley throes *AuthFailtureError*

How can I disable the security check?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not already have it in your web.config file, include or change authentication mode to `None`:

```
<!-- Web.config file -->
<system.web>
   <authentication mode="None" />
</system.web>
```

For more information refer this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291347%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).